# localStorage <-> Relational Database in the server

Tags: php, synchronization, backend

I have made a simple web app, which runs completely offline - all data is saved in HTML5's localStorage. Now, I want the data to get synced with the server, so that the user is able to use the app on multiple devices at a time.

What I have done so far is:

For each operation the user performs, a log entry is added.
When the user is online, all logs are transferred from localStorage to PHP through AJAX.
Corresponding changes are made in the SQL Database.
All logs are deleted from the localStorage.
So, all the localStorage data is getting "backed up" on the server properly.

Anyhow, changes made from one device is not being reflected to the other device and vice-versa, to do this, we would have to get some data from SQL to the localStorage.

Now, my question is as to what will be the appropriate and best way to do this?

After the four steps above, do I

1. Clear all localStorage data and save the SQL data into localStorage.
2. Keep a log of changes made in the database, and do them on the localStorage.
3. Any other approach.

Also, what about timestamps? What if there are conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on your logic when you want to sync data.**

If you want to copy your local Storage data to server, then you should make some flag saying you are ready to over accept data.

If your server have updated copy(newer version), then firstly updated data should be copied to your local Storage. And so on. Then changes sync from local to server again.

Anyhow it depends on what data you want to sync from server to local or local to server.

**Update**

I would say use 1st approach. Clear all localStorage data and save the SQL data into localStorage.

Because whenever local get copied to server. Server will have fresh copy other devices would have outdated data. Need to sync data by clearing data and saving SQL data to localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently when developing chrome extension. You should take a look at [Hood.ie](http://hood.ie/) (built on top of Node.js and CouchDB) which does the job for you automatically.

It's offline by default. It means that it stores data locally first and sync it in the background when possible. You don't have to worry about internet connection and exceptions that may occur when sending data. You can automatically subscribe to changes in remote database via events to get your local config updated.

Moreover, it has built-in user management system, so it means that data send to the database is sandboxed within logged user. You can share some parts of data between selected users or even access all of their data by the API (if enabled).

The website states that Hood.ie is in early-development. I've chatted with authors recently and they say that now it's stable enough to give it a try in the production environment. After few weeks of playing around with this, I haven't encountered any problems.